# How to get multiple language filename in directory using batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm using `.bat` file with `dir/b>filenamelist.xls` script but the other language character like below image:

[image: screenshot 1]

This is my folder with multiple language:

[image: screenshot 2]

How to generate Excel list of filename with all language?

Comment: This is impossible because batch cannot understand other languages except English.

Comment: If it is impossible using cmd, any other option? apps/software that can do?

Comment: had you tried to open the file with notepad++ ?

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1: Default Windows CMD**

If you have to use Windows CMD try to use **chcp** for each language you have, then concatenate the files after cleaning the unneeded duplicates.

```
REM 1256 is for Arabic 
chcp 1256 
dir /b >filenames-1256.txt

REM 866 is for Cyrillic (Russian)
chcp 866
dir /b >filenames-866.txt

REM 936 is for (Chinese)
chcp 936
dir /b >filenames-936.txt
```

Follow this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers)  to find the code page you need.

Then open each file in Notepad++ and change the encoding of **each file** to the corresponding code page used before, to view your filenames correctly:

[image]

**Method 2: [ConEMU](https://www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html) (CMD Alternative)**

To get all the results in a simple UTF-8 txt file, you can use [ConEmu](https://www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html) as a CMD alternative and execute your command directly

```
dir /b >filenames.txt
```

You will get all the filenames, written in their respective languages, in a simlpe UTF-8 txt file.
[image]